# How to set proxy for JMeter from behind another proxy?

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I'm new to jmeter.
I'm trying to test a web app using proxy server.
I have gone through the jmeter docs and got the settings but I'm currently working under company proxy.

So how can I set the proxy server for jmeter from behind the current proxy?

Answer (score 22):

Read :

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

*If you are testing from behind a firewall/proxy server, you may need to provide JMeter with the firewall/proxy server hostname and port number.*

*To do so, run the jmeter.bat/jmeter file from a command line with the following parameters:*
- '-H' [proxy server hostname or ip address] 
- '-P' [proxy server port] 
- '-N' [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost) 
- '-u' [username for proxy authentication - if required] 
- '-a' [password for proxy authentication - if required]

Example :

> jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost

Alternatively, you can use --proxyHost, --proxyPort, --username, and --password

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Comment: if the username contains "/" symbol and password contains "@" symbol, how to write the command line correctly? I tried using "/" and "@" directly or changing them to as "%5C" and "%40", but neither succeed.

Comment: For using password containing special characters, you need to do html encoding instead of url encoding. E.g. `&` need to be replaced by `&#0026;` instead of `%26`. For all chracters, refer this wiki page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 11):

Change Port and Proxy on **JMeter 5.0**

- used the Proxy and the Port below Just as example , it was origenal answer for this question - [Cannot capture jmeter traffic in fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622397/cannot-capture-jmeter-traffic-in-fiddler/56110552#56110552)

**UI Mode**

1. Create Thread Group --> HTTP Request
2. Go to Advanced fill "Server Name or IP:" = 127.0.0.1 , "Port Number:" = 8888
3. [image]

**Non UI MODE**

1. Add to your command  -H 127.0.0.1 for Proxy Host
2. -P 8888  for Proxy port
3. Example:
   C:\jmeter5.0\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\example.jmx -l C:\scriptresults.jtl **-H 127.0.0.1 -P 8888**