# Cannot capture jmeter traffic in fiddler

Tags: jmeter, fiddler

I created a JMeter recording. But when I start the Test,
I don't see any request going in Fiddler. I changed the 
port number in Fiddler to 8080, that I am using in JMeter.

Steps:

1. Create a Thread Group
2. Add Http Request to the Thread Group and enter URL
3. Add Recording Controller to the Thread Group
4. Add HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
5. Change Firefox settings to localhost proxy and 8080 port
6. Record Test
7. Then start Fiddler and start the test

I am not sure whether JMeter is really running the test successfully.
However it is showing the number of users as 10 and no errors when I 
run the test. Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 22):

First, change Fiddler's port back to `8888` as it was originally.

Next, change JMeter's proxy settings to point at `127.0.0.1` on port `8888` as its proxy settings.

Then, run your test.

Comment: Thanks. It works for for a HTTP Request sampler. But there's no such option to supply proxy settings on a SOAP/XML test sampler for web services. I am not able to capture the traffic in fiddler when testing my web service via JMeter.

Comment: JMeter allows you to specify a proxy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669947/how-to-set-proxy-for-jmeter-from-behind-another-proxy and you can also typically set the proxy settings for the Java VM itself.

Comment: Thanks Eric. But I made it work by adding a "HTTP Request Defaults" config element under the SOAP/XML sampler and specified the proxy settings (IP: 127.0.0.1, Port: 8888) in the "HTTP Request Defaults" config element. And now fiddler is able to capture the traffic from JMeter when testing a web service also.

Comment: I can confirm that this works for HTTPS requests. The requests to get authentication tokens can also be viewed normally. The "View Results Tree" is aligned with Fiddler.

Answer (score 6):

To record traffic from JMeter via Fiddler use the next setup 
**Importent**

- I used JMeter 5.0
- Recheck that  your Fiddler listing port set to 8888

**UI Mode**

1. Create Thread Group --> HTTP Request
2. Go to Advanced fill "Server Name or IP:" = 127.0.0.1 , "Port Number:" = 8888
3. [image]

**Non UI MODE**

1. Add to your command  -H 127.0.0.1 for Proxy Host
2. -P 8888  for Proxy port
3. Example:
   C:\jmeter5.0\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\example.jmx -l C:\scriptresults.jtl **-H 127.0.0.1 -P 8888**

Answer (score 4):

I would not suggest using fiddler as JMeter has its own recorder now.

To record a series of requests you need to follow the below steps.

1. Open JMeter
2. Right-click on 'Test Plan' and navigate to 'Threads (Users)' under 'Add' menu and then choose 'Thread Group'
3. Now, right-click on 'Thread Group' and navigate to 'Login Controller' under 'Add' menu and then choose 'Recording Controller'
4. Now right-click on 'Test Plan' again then navigate to 'Non-Test Elements' under 'Add' menu and then click on 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder'
5. Now without making any changes, click on the start button in the right section and then move to your browser.
6. Now configure your browser to use the proxy
   Host: localhost
   Port: 8888 (You can change this if you have changed the same in JMeter but make sure both have same values)
7. Now browse the internet as you normally do.

The above procedure will enable you to record traffic without hassles.
Remember, this will work for websites without HTTPS only.

You can refer to this video in case you feel confused: https://youtu.be/zXHs5Ts6JBc